# Stopping a LocationListener Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I want to stop `LocationListener`, but using a `Log`, I´ve found out that my service is still running after `removeUpdates()` method (When the location changes, it´s inserted into my log). Do you know where the problem is? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener {

 private final static String TAG = "MyService";
 LocationManager lm;

     public MyService() {
     }

     ....//Other methods here

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
         Log.d(TAG, loc.toString());
         if(/*A condition, which has to stop the service when it´s time*/) 
         {
             lm.removeUpdates(this);
             lm = null;
         }
    }

    public void subscribeToLocationUpdates() {
        this.lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }
```

}

I call this service in another Activity, onCreate method:

```
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                 MyService.class.getName());
    ComponentName service = startService(new Intent().setComponent(comp));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Service** object and its lifecycle is independent of the state of your location manager. or any other object for that matter.
A service represents a background part of your app. once you are done with it you can call `finish()` method to end it.

So in your case :

```
   public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
     Log.d(TAG, loc.toString());
     if(/*A condition, which has to stop the service when it´s time*/) 
     {
         lm.removeUpdates(this);
         lm = null;
         stopSelf(); // end this service
     }
}
```

Please take a look at android's Service documentation to get a general overview of its nature : [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the method `finish()` is undefined for the type MyService

Comment: That is the problem, `stopSelf` is not working too. It seems that Service is destroyed, but the new Service is created (GPS coordinates are displaying in log after `stopSelf`).

Comment: There is no new service created unless you are requesting it explicitly. please double check your code that starts the service